# UnsatisfiedLinkError when run System.loadLibrary

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip, pjsua2

I am using pjsip library through android ndk. I used Android NDK 16 to compile pjsip. One user (HTC One, Android 5.0.2) faced a lot of crashes while trying to start our project. This is the error:

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "stdin" referenced by "libpjsua2.so"...
... .PjSipApp.<clinit>
```

In the project we have .so-files for 4 abis, as stated in google android ndk official docs: arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64.
Here is how I load libraries in code:

```
public class PjSipApp {
    private static final String TAG = "Pjsua-PjSipApp";

    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("openh264");
            System.loadLibrary("yuv");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ignore) {
        }
        System.loadLibrary("pjsua2");
        Log.v(TAG, "LibraryLoaded");
    }...
```

So `System.loadLibrary("pjsua2");` throws this `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.
Maybe anyone knows, what is the reason for this?

Comment: I've 32bit .so file. Do you know how to create 64bit .so file? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably compiled binaries with a higher API Level.

This is how they are defined in [`stdio.h`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/include/stdio.h)

```cpp
#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 23
extern FILE* stdin __INTRODUCED_IN(23);
extern FILE* stdout __INTRODUCED_IN(23);
extern FILE* stderr __INTRODUCED_IN(23);
/* C99 and earlier plus current C++ standards say these must be macros. */
#define stdin stdin
#define stdout stdout
#define stderr stderr
#else
/* Before M the actual symbols for stdin and friends had different names. */
extern FILE __sF[] __REMOVED_IN(23);
#define stdin (&__sF[0])
#define stdout (&__sF[1])
#define stderr (&__sF[2])
#endif
```

So, if you built for API level >= 23, the symbol will resolve to `File* stdin` which doesn't exist in API < 23. I'd suggest to reduce the API level.

Comment: thank you, you are right. I tried to build with setting lower APP_PLATFORM and it worked. But I also wonder, does it influence on the security issues (or maybe any other issue, for instance, performance) if I build for lower version the same library and it runs on the newer devices?

Comment: @alla I don't think there'd be any issues related to security if you targeted lower APIs. Though there may be performance benefits of using newer APIs (and easy of use of course). If you're using play store, you can always publish two separate APKs one for lower and one for higher.